# Displaying multiple message dialogs in a CL Java program

Tags: java, modal-dialog, exit

For debugging purposes I want to fire up multiple message dialogs while running a Java program. (They contain graphical representations of some data structures.) This means the dialogs should be modeless, otherwise I can only have one of them at any time. But now the dialogs do not prevent the main program from exiting, and this in turn kills the dialogs.

I am using `System.exit` since otherwise the main program will not exit at all after some dialog has been fired up - modal or modeless, closed or not.

What I want is an easy way to check if there are still some visible (modeless) dialogs around, before calling `System.exit`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Window.getWindows()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#getWindows%28%29) to get reference to all windows, and check if they are visible with [Window.isShowing()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#isShowing%28%29).  Worth to note that windows that have been hidden but not [disposed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29) will still prevent Java from exiting.

You also could also `dispose()` these windows and then the JVM should exit by itself (no more need for `System.exit()`) after the main program finishes executing.

Comment: That's pretty much what I was looking for, thanks a lot. Calling `dispose` on a modeless dialog may be neater, but you have to make sure this is done for _every_ dialog. As for `System.exit`, I know it is frowned upon but in a command-line application it can still be useful to have an exit value.